# Verilog coding errors

Tags: buffer, warnings, verilog

I am completely unfamiliar with Verilog and had some concerns with errors being printed by the console. I know always blocks don't allow wires -- I'm unsure about what assign would do, but I know for sure initialize will not produce what I want. I am unsure how to read the errors or interpret them, and I have looked online, but seem to not find much relating to my specific error.

```
     module project(input [2:0] p1, input [2:0] p2, input m1, input m2, output reg [6:0] winner);


       // reg mo;  //not allowed 
     // reg mop; //not allowed
always @(*)
begin
if(m1 > 0 )
    case(0)
        0: winner = 16;
        //1: mo = 32; 
        //2: mo = 64;
        //4: mo = 16;
    endcase

if(m2 > 0 )
    case(0)
        0: winner = 1;
        //16: mop = 2;
        //32: mop = 1;
        //64: mop = 4;
    endcase

winner = 0;
case(p1 + p2 + m1 + m2)

        //rock1 & rock2 => tie no one wins
        17: winner = 0; 
        //rock1 & paper2 => player2 won with paper
        33: winner = p2; 
        //rock1 & scissors2 => player1 won with rock
        65: winner = p1; 
        //paper1 & rock2 => player1 won with paper
        18: winner = p1; 
        //paper1 & paper2 => tie no one wins
        34: winner = 0; 
        //paper1 & scissors2 => player2 won with scissors
        66: winner = p2; 
        //scissors1 & rock2 => player2 won with rock 
        20: winner = p2; 
        //scissors1 & paper2 => player1 won with scissors
        36: winner = p1; 
        //scissors1 & scissors2 => tie no one wins
        68: winner = 0;
    endcase
 end
  endmodule
```

As for my errors:

```
WARNING:Par:283 - There are 8 loadless signals in this design. This design will cause Bitgen to issue DRC warnings.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal p1<0>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal p1<1>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal p1<2>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal p2<0>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal m1_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal m2_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal p2<1>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:Par:288 - The signal p2<2>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <p1<0>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <p1<1>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <p1<2>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <p2<0>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <m1_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <m2_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <p2<1>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <p2<2>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal
   does not drive any load pins in the design.
```

I apologize for the multiple lines, but I think it's just the same occurring so if I can figure one out I can do the next. I apologize if my question is confusing and I appreciate all your time and help for looking over this mess of code. I apologize for the messy code -- if one can even consider it code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While what sharvil111 said is true that `winner` is never assigned anything greater than 3-bits width (note that is only times it is are either commented out or negated by the assignment `winner = 0` right before your final case), this is not the source of those warnings. The issue you are facing is in this line: `case (p1 + p2 + m1 + m2)`. This expression results in a value that is 3-bits wide as the longest variables in this expression are `p1` and `p2` at 3-bits wide. Thus, the maximum value this expression could reach is 3'b7. Even if the addition was done to the maximum number of bits, it would only result in a maximum value of 16 (`3'b111 {=7} + 3'b111 {=7} + 1'b1 {=1} + 1'b1 {=1} = 5'b10000 {=16}`; note that you'd need to do something for Verilog to take the expression to be 5 bits and not 3, like add in a 5'b0 should work). The values in the case statement are all well above both these results, thus all of them are removed by the synthesis tool. Along with the above mentioned assignment of `winner = 0`, no matter what, `winner` will be 7'b0 and none of the inputs matter. As such, you get warnings.

If you read the warnings, it says `loadless signals`; this means that there are some signals in your design that drive no logic, ie, your logic is completely independent of those signals. As such, synthesis tool like to optimize those signals out to save space (you dont need to do all the logic needed to get a signal thats never used anywhere!). It claims there are 8 such signals and, if you notice the following warnings, goes on to list all of your inputs (`p1<1>_buf` is `p1[1]`, note that you have a grant total of 8 bits, thus 8 signals, as inputs). All the warnings relate to this issue.

Looking over your code, I think you didnt mean to add these signals. I think you meant to concatenate them, making a vector that is 8 bits long (`$size(p1) + $size(p2) + $size(m1) + $size(m2)`). To do this, you need to use the concatenation operator (`{}`) like so: `case ({p1, p2, m1, m2})` will make a vector of size 8 by putting the bits from each of the variable next to eachother. Example: `p1 = 3'b011; p2 = 3'b101; m1 = 1'b1; m2 = 1'b0; {p1, p2, m1, m2} = 8'b011_101_1_0;`

Comment: Yes, I just focused on the `winner` part of the entire issue. I also think that the concatenation operator must be the real intent of the OP. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the warning is due to some un-driven output. Your output is declared as `reg [6:0] winner` which is of 7 bits. It is driven by p1 or p2 input ports, which are declared as `reg [2:0] p1` and `reg [2:0] p2` respectively i.e. 3 bits each.

The bits 6 down-to 3 are never driven at the output. Hence, your synthesis tool issues this warning.

Try declaring output port as `reg [2:0] winner`. This may solve the issue.

For more information regarding to this warning, refer to [this](http://www.edaboard.com/thread230882.html) and [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823586/verilog-module-warning) links.